# Additional git commits not showing up on initial PR in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pull-request

I have a forked branch that was cloned from github.
I pushed a commit to the forked branch and created a PR to merge to the original branch. The PR looked fine.
Problem started when I pushed a second commit to the forked branch, I expected the PR to be auto-updated but the 2nd commit didn’t show up. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed the following steps and it worked for me.

1. Cloned a public repository to my Github account: https://github.com/AnilGithubber/Web-Dev-For-Beginners/ (Ref: Github1)
2. Forked this cloned repository to my another Github account: https://github.com/AnilKumarVallur/Web-Dev-For-Beginners (Ref: Github2)
3. Performed changes for rep in Github2, created the PR and not merged yet to Github1
4. Created another commit from Github2 and the new commit was automatically showing up in Github1

Does your forked repository says it is forked from?

Comment: The fork seems to be fine since the initial commit showed up and the PR to merge to the parent branch looked fine as well.

Comment: This issue seems to have resolved itself after sometime. The PR did get updated but there was a significant delay.